# How would you sample and store ultrasonic signals at 132 kHz using a microcontroller, Raspberry Pi, etc.?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, microphone

I am attempting to sample and store analog ultrasonic microphone data. I am sampling at 12-bits. My ADC can sample fast enough, but storing to QSPI NOR Flash IC proved too slow, as did transferring data out via 2.8 Mb/s UART to USB IC to a terminal program. I am attempting to sample and store data at a sample rate of about 132 kHz, so my sample and store time period should be no longer than 7.3 microseconds equates to a sampling frequency of about 137kHz.(The shortest period I achieved was 23.25 μs,) My goal for now is to be able to sample and store one second’s worth of data sampled at 132 kHz or higher.
I am working with an STM32F446RET6 microcontroller. Any suggestions/tips are greatly appreciated. I am currently looking into trying QSPI flash again.
Thank You

Comment: Please edit your post to include why 7.3us is a limit, as well as your fastest period of 23.25us -- that's a duration not a speed.

Comment: What resolution are you sampling at?

Comment: Why is 2.8 Mb/s too slow? 8 bit samples at 132 kHz should equal a data rate of 1.056 Mb/s. 16 bit samples would be twice that (2.112 Mb/s), but still within the allotted bandwidth. Are you transmitting the samples as a series of ASCII strings?

Comment: You are only managing to transmit one sample every 23,25 μs (a frequency of 43 kHz) even though your UART is configured for 2.8 Mb/s. Either each sample currently takes roughly 64 bits of data to send for some reason, or you have some kind of performance bottleneck in your code.

Comment: @jms. I am sending a string of number characters, 0 to 4095 for 12-bit resolution, and a comma at the end for importing into excel later. I am using an oscilloscope to measure the time it takes to send "4095," by toggling a GPIO before and after sending the character string. The sizeof() function reveals 6 bytes being sent taking 23.25uS when the UART is configured to 2.8Mb/s. I will attempt to reduce the resolution to 8 bits to send only one character. I will also be looking into trimming down the toggle and UART transmit HAL functions.

Comment: @BlueSock has it occured to you to send 4095 as a number, which is two bytes, instead of four byte string?

Comment: Your expectations are unrealistic. At that sample frequency & resolution you should be sending the data as binary numbers and turning them into ascii strings only after you've received and stored them on the PC.

Comment: Which ultrasonic microphone are you using?

Comment: Can you make the MCU to look like a USB sound card? They commonly work up to 192kHz at 24 bits per sample and two channels, so generally it is not a problem to record for hours with such a setup, given enough disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Break up your storage problem into several parts, from fastest and slowest. The fastest storage is SRAM, followed by Flash, then off-board UART transfer. With a sample rate of 132 kHz, this will produce a total of 264,000 bytes (kHz = 1,000) in the 1 second capture time, but the STM32F446RET6 only has 128KB of SRAM, so it won't all fit. But it will fit into the slower internal Flash memory.

Fine, just create the largest circular buffer in SRAM that you can afford. Be sure to dial down heap and stack to get the maximum memory available for this circular buffer. Next, create linear buffer in internal Flash memory, then use the DMA feature of the chip to transfer from the SRAM buffer to the Flash buffer. The idea is that although the Flash memory is too slow, it will offload the SRAM buffer enough so that near the end of the 1 second capture window it will be clear enough to hold the remaining data.

Only after all the data is transferred to Flash memory, do you want to start the UART transfer so that none of the cycles are interrupted (wasted) in the Flash transfer which is most critical.

Also, take note that Flash memory likes to be updated (written to) in chunks, not bytes, for the most efficient transfer speed. So setup the DMA to transfer in these chunk sizes only. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443619/how-to-write-read-to-flash-on-stm32f4-cortex-m4) for writing to internal Flash memory.

Since the SRAM buffer is circular design, it may not be easy to use a DMA channel for the ADC to SRAM transfer, so just let the CPU do these transfers inside a tight loop or an interrupt service routine. The CPU is fast enough anyway that this is no longer critical.

Comment: Correct answer. "Fine, just create the largest circular buffer in SRAM that you can afford." The rest is redundant. However you get one up from me. :-) The OP needs to calculate the queue size, along with the processing speed. Then the OP may try to find more memory somewhere. Sometimes, circular memory just is not good enough, need to have full-size.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to store so much data?  Are you trying to store each waveform echo?  Why?  Typically an ultrasonic sensor sends chirps and waits for the echo of the spchirp 8 to 20 full wavelengths, then sends another string of chirps and processes the previous string.  Each burst of chirps is typically spaced just a bit longer in time than the time it would take for an echo to return from the maximum expected distance the microphone can sense.

Only the processed data is typically saved - not each waveform.

Comment: I like this response, although it could be formatted better into an answer. Using the very fast STM32F446RET6 microcontroller, process the data in real time so that what is transferred is very small information and does not require fast throughput. Great idea!